# jQuery Ajax Error Response Contains The Success Response

Tags: jquery

This is a confusing one for me. When I run an ajax request it's always returning an error, but checking the response the data in the responseText is actually the data I need. So why is it reaching the error?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/getjson.php?name=jay",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
            alert("Error: " + msg.responseText);
    }

    });
```

Comment: We'd probably need to see your php code to be able to discern that. Also, if you open up the network tab in chrome developer tools / firebug, what response headers are you receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned HTTPStatus code is what jQuery uses to determine which handler to call.

If the code is in the 2 hundred range (200 - 299) or 304 then a call to the success callback will be made, otherwise the error callback will be called.

Also, if jQuery fails to parse the response, it is treated as an error (eg if html is returned when json is expected, the error callback will be called)

Comment: Yep, it's 200. Which is what's confusing.

Comment: Answer now updated with an alternate reason why the error callback is being called.

Comment: What's the best solution for this? I don't really want to have to resort to parsing the json response within the error. I have no control over the json once the code is in production, only on my development server for testing.

Comment: Fixed. Set the data type to text.

Answer (score 0):

change you error func to

```
error: function(jqXHR, error_textStatus, errorThrown)
```

and check these :

```
jqXHR.readyState     
jqXHR.status      // <=== specially this           
jqXHR.statusText         
jqXHR.responseText
```

Comment: readyState = 4, status = 200, statusText = OK, responseText = The response I should be getting on success.

Comment: Could it be because the JSON contains backslashes?